# Error handling for multiple modules in python

Tags: python, error-handling, python-module

I have a project that has multiple different modules.

```
project/
    read_email.py
    browse.py
    vsw.py
    mdf.py
    cill.py
    utils_funcs.py
```

So `read_email.py` reads an email and then invokes `vsw.py`

```
import win32com.client
from vsw import vsw
def read_email():

    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    pc_fold_struct = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + '\\Documents\\project\\'
    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

    messages = inbox.Items

    for message in messages:
        if message.Unread:
            vsw(pc_fold_struct)
```

In `vsw` I invoke other functions from the remaining modules.

from utils_funcs import click_item
from mdf import mdf
from browse import browse
from cill import cill
import os
def run_other_processes_while_vsw(pc_fold_struct):

```
cill_folder = pc_fold_struct + "Cill_Status\\"
if len(os.listdir(cill_folder)) == 0:
    cill()
    click_item(1, 1, "vsw_test_blue")
if len(os.listdir(pc_fold_struct + "MDF")) == 0:
    mdf()
    click_item(1, 1, "check_vsw")
if len(os.listdir(pc_fold_struct + 'browse')) == 0:
    browse()
    click_item(1, 1, "check_vsw")

def vsw(pc_fold_struct):

    #if the loop for click item is longer than 20 counts, break and go back to read email
    click_item(1, 1, "my_fav")
    click_item(1, 1, "vsw_test")   
    run_other_processes_while_vsw(pc_fold_struct)
```

Below is a small portion of my `mdf` function

```
 from utils_funcs import click_item
#mdf
 def mdf():
    #also here how to make it go back to read_email if `click_item` count is 20
    click_item(1, 1, "my_fav")
    click_item(1, 1, "mdf")
    #other code occurs here.
```

except for `utils_funcs.py`. This module is unique in the way I have a function `click_item` (below)

```
def click_item(time_one, time_two, img, **kwargs):

    dir_name = 'c:\\'
    coords = None
    while coords == None:
        try:
            time.sleep(time_one)
            coords = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(dir_name + "img\\" + img + ".png", grayscale=False)
            pyautogui.moveTo(x=coords.x, y=coords.y)
            pyautogui.click()
            time.sleep(time_two)
        except Exception as e:
            coords = None
```

That uses `pyautogui` to click an image. But I have used this function all across my other modules. As it is a continuous loop, if stuck in an error I want it to break the loop when the count is greater than 20 for example and then go back to the `read_email.py` module. The only way I could think to do this is to return something from the loop and go through each module checking if it is this variable if it is exit the program. So for example my function would become;

```
def click_item(time_one, time_two, img, **kwargs):

    dir_name = 'c:\\'
    coords = None
    count = 1
    while coords == None:
        try:
            time.sleep(time_one)
            coords = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(dir_name + "img\\" + img + ".png", grayscale=False)
            pyautogui.moveTo(x=coords.x, y=coords.y)
            pyautogui.click()
            time.sleep(time_two)
        except Exception as e:
            if count == 20:
                return True
            else:
                count += 1
                coords = None
```

But not sure how to process this in the other modules to allow it to go back to `read_email.py`

The reason I do not just let the process break is because the program that I am automating using `pyautogui` sometimes takes time to load the image. That is why is in the `click_item` function on the `except` I set `coords=None` however if it has not found the image after 20 times. Then this is an error and I need to revert back to read email.

Comment: You should raise the exception and handle it in the caller

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so for example do you mean in each module that invoke `click_item` wrap a try-except around it?

Comment: well, if the point is to have it fail, then you can just not handle that error. Then the program will terminate

Comment: problem with that is sometimes it needs to wait for an image to appear, but once it is greater than 20-30 times there has been error and I would like to go back to checking emails. If that makes sense

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. You need to provide a [mcve]. What does "read_email.py reads an email and then invokes vsw.py" mean, exactly?

Comment: I added more information in my question.